# How do you update dual/inverse hasMany relationships with Ember Data models where async is true?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two simple models in my Ember application that work like so:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  books: DS.hasMany('book', { async: true })
});
```

Users can easily add and remove tags to a given book via our UI. The code that runs when a user removes a tag, for example, is:

```
book.get('tags').removeRecord(tagToRemove);
book.save();
```

This works just fine in removing the tag from the book. However, the tag model itself still references the book. In other words, the inverse relationship is not automatically updated.

EDIT:

After doing a JS Bin (http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1574/edit), it seems the reason the tag's `books` property is not updating automatically is because of the `{ async: true }` option I passed. That said, I'm not sure I can really afford to remove that option, because a tag may have millions of books and I don't want to load all of them with the tag.

Any way to get things working as-is?

Answer (score 0):

The only way Ember Data would 'magically' remove from both is if you deleted the record.  If you just remove the record from one of the other records, technically Ember Data isn't positive you don't want to still have the other relationship from the other record to this record.

Comment: So I just did a JSBin and it seems this is not the case: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1574/edit

If you remove a tag from a book, both the book's tag count and the tag's book count decrease. So it seems you don't have to delete the book. It seems the reason things aren't working is because of the `async` option on one side of the relationship.